# How to tokenize string with alphabetical and numerical values

Tags: string, go, stringtokenizer

I have a string like "test123abc45alsdkfj", I want my scanner to behave such that it read `"test"` first, then `123`, then `"abc"`, then `45`, then `"alsdkfj"`. Kinda like stringstream in C++, is there a way to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: By "my scanner" do you refer to `text/scanner` package?

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a simple way like this, hope it will help you

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "text/scanner"
)

func isDigit(c byte) bool {
    if c >= 48 && c <= 57 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    const src = `test123abc45alsdkfj`

    var s scanner.Scanner
    s.Init(strings.NewReader(src))

    for tok := s.Scan(); tok != scanner.EOF; tok = s.Scan() {

        chars := s.TokenText()
        temp := string(chars[0])

        for i := range chars {
            if i > 0 {
                if isDigit(chars[i]) != isDigit(chars[i-1]) {
                    fmt.Println(temp)
                    temp = string(chars[i])
                } else {
                    temp += string(chars[i])
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and output will be

```
test
123
abc
45
```